# How to collapse sections in vscode when open file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need all sections to be collapsed (folded) when open document. I know about shortcut, but I need folding by default.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you opening documents?

Comment: Is it matter? Open folder => open file in explorer.